# Why does Wine copy all the files in the Home directory?

Tags: wine

Looking through my Wine's fake C: Drive, I see the files in my home directory (the files in my Desktop, Downloads, etc.) all copied in the C: Drive's home directory. Furthermore, if I make a new file, it automatically copies to here again. Is it necessary to have a duplicate of all folders in home directory in Wine? If not, is there a way to get rid of this feature?

Comment: Are you sure they aren't symlinks to those folders?

Comment: I did not check for that, how do I check if a folder is a symlink again?

Comment: if you run `ls -al` you can see if it's one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour of Wine is to create a "Wine prefix" containing a virtual "drive C:" with links to `~/Desktop`, `~/Documents`, `~/Music` etc. where Windows applications expect them. If you run

```
ls -l ~/.wine/drive_c/users/${USER}
```

you should see the symlinks involved.

This means any file you add to `~/Desktop` also shows up in your Wine desktop. The files aren't duplicated, they're just visible in two places because of the symlinks.